# UNIQUE KEY on NULL values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
TABLE place (
  place_id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  iso_code char(2) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (place_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (`iso_code`,`name`)
)
```

with sample data, like so:

```
place_id | iso_code | name
--------------------------
46       | es       | NULL
47       | es       | Madrid
48       | es       | Barcelona
49       | es       | NULL
50       | us       | Rome
51       | it       | Rome
52       | it       | NULL
```

For some reason, it looks like mysql doesn't seem to apply the constraint to `NULL` values. Look at `place_id` 46 and 49...

After some research, I realize that this is normal behaviour in mysql. So, my question is how do I make it so I don't have cases like `place_id` 46 and 49?

EDIT:
I'm using mysql 5.7.28

Answer (score 3):

Using function index and `COALESCE` with value that is outside column domain:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux ON place(`iso_code`, (COALESCE(`name`, '~')));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ace84fbdb36bd87ef3533625d7eb80a)**

Index on expression are supported with MySQL 8.0 and above.

Comment: I should specify that im using mysql 5.7.28. I looks like it doesn't work for that version, I get the error 'ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version...' I've edited my question...

Comment: @Marco Yes, this feature was introduced in MySQL 8.0+

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a trigger instead of a unique key:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER place_tr_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON place
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM place 
        WHERE iso_code = NEW.iso_code AND COALESCE(name, '') = COALESCE(NEW.name, '')
    ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate entry for key (`iso-code`, `name`)';
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And you will need to create another trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` with exactly the same body.

[Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rAq5ajnLCjwmuTSELM2VMj/0)